# Unable to locate package mingw32

Tags: ubuntu, android-source

Excuse me, I am compiling Android open source project(AOSP) on the Ubuntu 15.04 accroding to this web page(http://blog.logan.tw/2013/09/build-android-aosp.html), I need to install some tools by this command line:

```
sudo apt-get install git gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential \
    zip curl libc6-dev libncurses5-dev:i386 x11proto-core-dev \
    libx11-dev:i386 libreadline6-dev:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 \
    libgl1-mesa-dev g++-multilib gcc-multilib mingw32 tofrodos \
    python-markdown libxml2-utils xsltproc zlib1g-dev:i386
```

After that,

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mingw32
```

I tried to modify the file /etc/apt/sources.list 
original:

> deb http ://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted

result:

> deb http ://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main universe

It's not work for me, I don't know how to fix this problem:
**E: Unable to locate package mingw32**
Help me please! Thanks!

Comment: This question would find a better answer on our sister-site, [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have You done an `apt-get update` after changing `sources.list` ?
(You have to do that sometimes even without changes if a package
could be find in the repos)

What do You get by `apt-cache search mingw` ?

Comment: sorry, this is not an answer yet, more a comment

Comment: I have done an "apt-get update", but it doesn't work for me. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I followed your comments but the problem remains. Why?

Answer (score 4):

Starting with Ubuntu 15.04, the `mingw32` package is no longer available; it has been replaced by the `mingw-w64` package, which you should install instead. You might also need to adjust the compilation instructions to use `i686-w64-mingw32` as the target instead of `i586-mingw32msvc`.